# File Loop Function

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I am creating a function in node.js that loops through the files of a directory. It is supposed to add the file name to the returnData variable, then return the returnData. However, it keeps returning nothing. I've put a few console.log statements in the function to help me debug, but I can't figure out why it won't work.

```
function loopMusic (directory) {
    var returnData = "";
    fs.readdir (directory, function (err, files) {

        if (err) {
            console.log (err);
        }

        files.forEach (function (file, index) {
            returnData += file;
            console.log (returnData);
        });
    });
    console.log (returnData);
    return returnData;
}
```

The first console.log statement is able to print the files, but the one right before the return just prints a new line.

Comment: You need to do some research on asynchronous code and how callbacks work.

Comment: `fs.readdir` is async, thus it is called later then the method is returned. The filesystem library in nodejs does alow for synchronous calls which is called `readdirSync` and returns an array of strings.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Answer (score 2):

You can make the function return a promise:

```
function loopMusic (directory) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      fs.readdir (directory, function (err, files) {

          if (err) {
            reject(err);
            return;
          }

          files.forEach (function (file, index) {
              returnData += file;
              console.log (returnData);
          });

          resolve(returnData);
    });
}
```

You would use in that way:

```
loopMusic('...')
   .then((data) => console.log(data))
   .catch((err) => ...);
```

Comment: That's true!  I will fix it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`fs.readdir` is asynchronous, meaning it does not return with the result when you call it.  Instead the result is provided to the callback, which is called when the command finishes processing. It "calls-back" to the function you provided when it's done (hence the name).

If you wanted to do this synchronously you can do the following:

```
function loopMusic (directory) {
    var returnData = "";
    var files = fs.readdirSync(directory);
    files.forEach (function (file, index) {
        returnData += file;
        console.log (returnData);
    });
    console.log(files);
    return returnData;
}
```

That would return a string of mushed together file paths, as in your question.

However, blocking isn't usually a good idea and you should use the asynchronous version.  I like to return a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) in these situations.  Here's an example that returns a promise filled with that string.  This technically isn't necessary since the callback could just be used...but lets just pretend.

```
function loopMusic (directory) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        fs.readdir (directory, function (err, files) {
            if (err) {
                return reject(err);
            }

            let returnData = "";
            files.forEach (function (file, index) {
                returnData += file;
            });

            resolve(returnData);        
        });
    });
}
```

Usage:

```
var musicPromise = loopMusic(dir);
musicPromise.then((musicStr) => console.log(musicStr)), (err) => console.log(err));
```

The asynchronous nature of this makes it a bit hard to follow since things don't happen in order, but when using Promises the `then()` is used to handle what happens on success (or failure) when it does complete later on.

Finally, if you're using ES2017+ (the newest version of Node) you can use the `async/await` pattern.  Keep in mind my promise example above:

```
async function loopMusicAsync(directory) {
    try{
        return await loopMusic(directory); //promise returned
    }
    catch(error) {
        console.log(error); //promise rejected
        return null;
    }
}
```